# How to test legacy C code and check which branches where hit

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, legacy-code

I have a DLL which contains many large (1000+ line) functions. This code has lots of complex logic which I want to ensure doesn't get broken when its maintained so I created a test harness which dynamically loads this DLL and calls its API.

I would like to know a nice way of being able to test which branches of the code where hit within this API from my test harness. The only way I can think of doing this is as follows:

```
// Pseudo test code
void doTest()
{
  loadDllToBeTested();
  dll_api_function_1();
  assert( dll_api_function_1_branches.branch1Hit == true );
  unloadDllToBeTested();
}


 // Real api in the C dll
 struct dll_api_function_1_branches
 {
   bool branch1Hit;
 }

 dll_api_function_1_branches g_dll_api_function_1_branches;

 int private_func1()
 {
     printf("Doing my private stuff\n");
     return 1;
 }

 void dll_api_function_1(void)
 {
   if ( private_func1() )
   {
     printf("doing some stuff\n");
     dll_api_function_1_branches.branch1Hit = true; // so the test code can check if we got here :(
 }
 else
 {
    printf("doing some other stuff\n");
 }

 // tons of other logic and branching...
 }
```

Which is basically have a struct per function which has values set when certain branches are reached within the function. There would be a global exported instance of this struct which the test code would have to init to zero and then check after calling the API.

Also note that I'm using Visual Studio so tools like gcov can't be used here.

Comment: gcc has a code coverage tool,  but you might have to d o some work to hook it into your test harness. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Visual C++ so I can't use gcov, I'll update my tags.

Comment: A quick search for "visual c++ code coverage" on the internet seems to turn up quite a few links. Had any look at those? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=visual+c%2B%2B+code+coverage

Comment: There is a coverage tool in Visual Studio which people say is very good. See e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810224/visual-studio-2012-code-coverage). I have no experience with it. There are also third party automated coverage tools. Your solution is error-prone and doesn't scale well. Go with an automated tool.

Comment: But is it possible to say, run N unit tests and then check in code if 100% coverage was attained?

Answer (score 1):

The LLVM project mentions the [KLEE](http://klee.llvm.org/TestingCoreutils.html) tool, which helps creating test cases to exercise all paths (and find bugs in the process). Some of it is strongly Unix-oriented, and it is a current research project (rough edges, some assembly required, and the other disclaimers).